# Popover presentation showing blank/white view in xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got a big project where I want to make a popover in 1 of my views, when click on a button.

The problem is that when I click the button it just shows a view with nothing in.
I have tried make a new project and do the same where it works fine, no problems there..

How I done it.
Made a new view, freeform it so it is the size I want.
Den from the button in other view I control+drag over to the new view and choose Present as Popover. But it just wont show the things I have in the new view, where it here is just a label, and have constraint on it show it should be in the middle of the view, and have tried moving it around, to see if any effects with that, but nothing happens..

I also have something else happen when click on the button, but tried removing that, and that did not help either.. Have also tried making button other places in my app, but it is the same problem.

I have not wrote code for it, just done it in the storyboard.

Screenshot from storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm9My.png

Screenshot from app showing the view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN6sP.png

Comment: Of what?
There is no code for this. It is done in the storyboard only.

Comment: I tried it myself the way you described, its the proper way and seems to be working fine here.

Comment: Yeah. I also have no problem when making a new clean project, there it works perfect. But here in my big project it is a problem.. And I have tried delete and redo a lof of time.
But cant find out what the problem is in my project.

Comment: May be 'Hello' text is in the center and you are not able to see it. Drag it to top left. Just saying!

Comment: Tried that too. Did not work. Also tried to insert a image that took up all the view, did not work either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did found out what the problem was.
I had changed from wAny hAny too wRegular hAny because only making for iPad.
I found out that was mistake to do it this way. Because then the popover show in the app would be wAny hAny instead of the wRegular hAny I was working on in the storyboard..

So changed to wAny hAny and then I instead changed to iPad view under Simulated Metrics instead of to see how it look on iPad.

Comment: thanks man, i had done the same thing been looking around for hours!!